# Ble pairing/bond issues with samsung

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile, beacon, altbeacon

I've an HM10 configured as ibeacon connectable.
Every time i enter in beacon region i connect to ble device.
The ble device is configured to pair with a pin.
On samsung s8,samsuns ace, some huwei as p8 and p9 after some connection so requires again the pin.
On lg g5, huawei p10 and p9 no issues.
Someone knows why this bond loss?

Comment: You should look at the logcat logs and the hci snoop log to find out why this happens. It's hard to help with so few details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved.
Seems using ble search/new ble connection while or near the beacon search causes the issue.
Posted the issue in altbeacon library even if i think is a samsung, huawei fast race similar bug